# Difference between "\\d+" and "\\d++" in java regex

Tags: java, regex

In java, what's the difference between `"\\d+"` and `"\\d++"`?
I know ++ is a possessive quantifier, but what's the difference in matching the numeric string? 
What string can match `"\\d+"` but can't with `"\\d++"`?
Possessive quantifier seems to be significant with quantifier `".*"` only. Is it true?

Answer (score 13):

Possessive quantifiers will not back off, even if some backing off is required for the overall match.

So, for example, the regex `\d++0` can never match any input, because `\d++` will match all digits, including the `0` needed to match the last symbol of the regex.

Answer (score 3):

**\d+ Means:**
`\d` means a digit (Character in the range 0-9), and `+` means 1 or more times. So, `\d+` is 1 or more digits.

**\d++ Means**  from [Quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

> This is called  the possessive quantifiers and they always eat the entire input string, trying once (and only once) for a match. Unlike the greedy quantifiers, possessive quantifiers never back off, even if doing so would allow the overall match to succeed.

Comment: The question is about `\d++`.

Comment: The quote in your answer is incorrect, and it can't be found on the page you linked to. Possessive quantifiers don't always "eat the entire input string".